# Libgdx logging wrong integer with ClickListener

Tags: java, button, libgdx

I'm having a problem with my libgdx ClickListener.

When I Initialise my buttons and add a new ClickListener to each of them in a forloop all of the buttons log the last Int from the forloop instead of the number I created them with.

Why does this happen and what is the best way to fix this problem?

```
for(i = 0; i<data.getLevelData().size(); i++){
    buttonstyle = new ImageButtonStyle();
    buttonstyle.up = skin.getDrawable("pause-up");
    buttonstyle.down = skin.getDrawable("pause-down");
    buttonstyle.pressedOffsetX = 1; 
    buttonstyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;

        button.add(new ImageButton(buttonstyle));

    button.get(i).addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override 
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
            Gdx.app.log( "test", "" + i);
        }
    });
    table.add(button.get(i)).expandX().pad(3).height(64).width(64);

    rowcounter++;

    if(rowcounter>5){
        table.row();
        rowcounter = 0;
    }
}
```

I hope someone knows how to solve this problem thx for reading/helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all looking at the same `i` that you initialized in your for loop. Make a copy of it unique to each listener like this:

```
final int iCopy = i;
button.get(i).addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override 
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
        Gdx.app.log( "test", "" + iCopy);
    }
});
```

The `final` qualifier ensures the value cannot change from what you initialized it as. Since `iCopy` has scope inside the for-loop instead of outside it like `i`, a unique version of it is created for each listener.

Comment: Thanks alot thats exactly what I was looking for!